# Bibiography not showing up

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm running on TexMaker the following code (from https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX#The_bibliography_file)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and the Dirac's 
book \cite{dirac} are physics related items. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I'm pressing F1 to compile but no bibliography shows up. What should I do?

---

My Quick Build cycle is: PdfLaTex + Biblatex + PdfLaTex (x2) + Pdf Viewer

I have also tried to delete the Biber cache, reboot TexMaker and compile again but nothing showed up anyways.

Comment: You have to follow the normal cycle: `(pdf)latex ->biber -> (pdf)latex (twice)`. Is F1 set to perform all this cycle?

Comment: Have you made sure that your editor actually calls Biber for you? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. If Biber is run, you should find a `.blg` file (Windows may classify `.blg` files as 'performance monitor' files, but they are simple text files you can open with your favourite text editor). Post its complete contents here.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, it does

Comment: Any news here? Did you go through the instructions in the linked question to make sure your editor runs Biber and not BibTeX for you? If so, did it work? If not, can you explain why the linked answers were inadequate? If you can now run Biber and still don't get the desired outcome, please show us the `.blg` file. If there is no new development here in due time I will vote to close this question as duplicate of the "configure your editor for Biber" question.